# _mm_mulhi_epi16 equivalent on ARM

Tags: c, arm, arm64, neon

I am working on a project to accelerate the perf on ARM platform with NEON intrinsics.

I could not find the direct equivalents for below intrinsics
_mm_mulhi_epi16
_mm_hadd_epi32
_mm_maddubs_epi16
_mm_madd_epi16
_mm_extract_epi8

Equivalent intrinsics will help a lot in my efforts

Comment: Direct equivalents don't necessarily exist, e.g. none for `_mm_mulhi_epi16` that I know of.  You could emulate it with `smull` and some permutation, but it's probably better to step back and look at your actual algorithm instead of trying to replace instructions one-for-one.  There may be another way to implement it that better fits the instructions that ARM64 actually has.

Comment: `vqdmulh_s16` is it. You can even round the value with `vqrdmulh_s16`

Comment: Beware though, the instruction results in q15 while Intel's in q14.

Comment: In general this is a good source of inspiration  https://github.com/DLTcollab/sse2neon

Answer (score 2):

`_mm_hadd_epi32` appears to match [`vpaddq_s32`](https://developer.arm.com/architectures/instruction-sets/intrinsics/vpaddq_s32).

`_mm_extract_epi8` appears to match [`vgetq_lane_s8`](https://developer.arm.com/architectures/instruction-sets/intrinsics/vgetq_lane_s8).

Not sure about the others offhand.